# Avoid escape double quotes in bash when read from file

Tags: bash

I have following file content:

```
1:"z:\raws\data\fractal\todo_1.*"
2:"z:\raws\data\fractal\todo_2.*"
3:"z:\raws\data\fractal\todo_3.*"
...
```

reading content as array, I do with `cat`

```
args=($(cat file.txt))
```

Then I want to pass arguments to an executable like:

`./path/to/executable ${args[@]}`

But somehow will become:

`./path/to/executable 1:\"z:\raws\data\fractal\todo_1.*\" 2:\"z:\raws\data\fractal\todo_2.*\"`

There's a way to remove `\"` and leave as `"` instead ?

like outout:

`./path/to/executable 1:"z:\raws\data\fractal\todo_1.*" 2:"z:\raws\data\fractal\todo_2.*"`

Comment: Are these received in your executable as `\\"`? Because perhaps it's just escaping them for `bash` to correctly call the command?

Comment: [edit] your question to tell us hw you know that `./path/to/executable ${args[@]}` somehow will become `./path/to/executable 1:\"z:\raws\data\fractal\todo_1.*\" 2:\"z:\raws\data\fractal\todo_2.*\"`. I suspect you're misinterpreting the output of something and that is actually not what's happening. Change `./path/to/executable ${args[@]}` to `printf '%s\n' "${args[@]}"` to see if the values in `args[]` are really having their double quotes escaped when passed to the command or not then [edit] your question to show us that output.

Comment: Don't use `bash` to process this file; use a language with a CSV parser (most such parsers don't really care what character is used as a delimiter, and let you specify comma, tab, *colon*, whatever is actually used by the file).

Comment: You could use `tr` for removing all the quotes, while reading the file (see the section titled _Process substitution_ in the bash man-page). But will this be sufficient? According to your posting, you also have as prefix a number, followed by a colon. Shouldn't this be removed as well?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t args < file.txt

printf '%s\n' "${args[@]}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
1:"z:\raws\data\fractal\todo_1.*"
2:"z:\raws\data\fractal\todo_2.*"
3:"z:\raws\data\fractal\todo_3.*"
```

Replace `printf '%s\n'` with `./path/to/executable` for whatever command you want to pass the `args[]` content to.